# Directus Create API in local

Tags: rest, next.js, directus

I'm downloading diretcus on my PC using npm and create init file using `directus init` and select MySQL and setup successful and input data in model using login in directus in local, but now I want to create an API for use in Next, but I don't know how to create someone. Please help me.
and please guide me to create an API.

I need to create an API for my model in a directus local environment..